# Prestashop console error "TypeError: jsonData is null"

Tags: php, ajax, prestashop, cart

I'm a newbie in Prestashop and I have problem. When somebody click the button "Add to cart", console shows error "TypeError: jsonData is null" and you can't see that product added to the cart, but if you refresh the page it will appears there.
May somebody help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to open your developper console on chrome (or firefox), go to network tab, click on the "add to cart" again and watch what happened. The result is not JSON as expected or at least just corrupted JSON.

The problem is in the cart, the answer returned by Prestashop when you push the button is in JSON.

Comment: It returns me 'null'.

Comment: I find why the problem was. File blockcart-json.tpl in blockcart was empty.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the all the contents of "/themes/default-bootstrap/modules/ blockcart" directory from the raw PrestaShop installation of same PrestaShop version.

Note: Don't forget to take a backup of the original file before replacing them.